# Using String Function Parameter as Class Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have method as below

```
public void UpdateDb(int id)
{
    var UpdateMyModel = db.CRM_OPP_DETAILS
        .Where(p=> p.ID == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    UpdateMyModel .IS_VALID = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can i use the 'ModelName string parameter' as model class name. IE. as below:

```
public void UpdateDb(string ModelName , int id)
{
    var UpdateMyModel = db.""ModelName ""
        .Where(p=> p.ID == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    UpdateMyModel.IS_VALID = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: So you're using an ORM and you want to use the table name in your code?

Comment: Even your pseudo is wrong, the second `TableName` should just be UpdateTable as it is the variable already containing the `TableName`. Plus: what @ken2k said...

Comment: are you able to make all your entities implement an interface that provides ID and IS_VALID?

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could archieve this by using generics and interfacing. The datacontext supports a [`GetTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.gettable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

You would use it for example like this:

```
public void UpdateDb<T>(int id) where T : IUpdateDbInterface
{
    var UpdateTable = db.GetTable<T>()
                        .Where(p=> p.ID == id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    UpdateTable.IS_VALID = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}

interface IUpdateDbInterface {
    int ID { get; set;}
    bool IS_VALID { get; set;}
}
```

To call it:

```
UpdateDb<MyRecordType>(1234);
```

Your generic type `T` will require an interface constraint defining at least `int ID` and `bool IS_VALID` otherwise the generic code will not know its type `T` has these fields available. And then of course the tables you want to be able to run this on all need to implement this interface.

---

If you do insist on using strings, use the [`Type.GetType( ... )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to get your string class name into a `Type`. Then you could use the method as such:

```
public void UpdateDb(Type type, int id)
{
    var UpdateTable = db.GetTable(type)

    .....
}
```

But you will still need the interface stuff to get to your properties. Or use reflection for everything, but this seriously makes no sense when using an ORM.

Comment: can i put a string variable into UpdateDb<MyRecordType>

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d/linq-to-sql-dynamic-sql-table-name?forum=linqprojectgeneral      or this   http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/linq-questions/table-name-as-a-parameter.aspx

Comment: Using a string as table name makes no sense at this point. You could alter the method to use the overload of `GetTable()` that takes a Type rather than a Generic, and construct the type from a string using reflection.

Comment: I am not able to call db.GetTable().. Do i need to include something ?

Comment: @modulerica which `ORM` do you use? Entity Framework?